# how to extract the journals names from a PubMed

Tags: r

I am trying to perform a search on specific authors

so I can look up but I don't know how to extract citation, or plot journals that he or she published papers in

```
library(RISmed)
#now let's look up this author
res <- EUtilsSummary('Gene Myers', type='esearch', db='pubmed')
summary(res)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to notice is that what you already produced contains the PubMed IDs 
for the papers that match your query.

```
res@PMID
 [1] "30481296" "29335514" "26102528" "25333104" "23541733" "22743769"
 [7] "21685076" "20937014" "20122179" "19447790" "12804086" "12061009"
```

Knowing the IDs,  you can retrieve detailed information on all of them
using `EUtilsGet`

```
res2 = EUtilsGet(res@PMID)
```

Now we can get the items required for a citation from res2.

```
ArticleTitle(res2)          ## Article Titles
Title(res2)                 ## Publication Names
YearPubmed(res2)            ## Year of publication
Volume(res2)                ## Volume
Issue(res2)                 ## Issue number
Author(res2)                ## Lists of Authors
```

There is much more information embedded in the `res2` object. 
If you look at the help page `?Medline`, you can get a good idea 
of the other information.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried to do it though this `fetch.pubmed <- entrez_fetch(db = "pubmed", id = ids, rettype = "xml")`  . Is there a way to get the citation too?

Comment: I do not believe that there is a single item that returns a citation. I think of a citation as being made up of the components above (title, publication name, year, etc). I think that you must put these together to make your own citation.  Is there some component of the citation beyond those that I have given that you need?

Comment: I already liked and accepted your answer. Thanks I will try to play around with the direction you gave me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you retrieve the detailed information of the selected articles using `EUtilsGet`, the journal information is stored as ISO abbreviated term.

```
library(RISmed)
#now let's look up this author
res <- EUtilsSummary('Gene Myers', type='esearch', db='pubmed')
summary(res)
res2 = EUtilsGet(res, db = "pubmed")
sort(table(res2@ISOAbbreviation), decreasing = T)[1:5]             ##Top 5 journals

   Gigascience     Bioinformatics      J Comput Biol BMC Bioinformatics          Curr Biol 
             3                  2                  2                  1                  1
```